# How to run many jobs on Azure with easy lifecycle management

Tags: azure

My scenario is like that: I want to have a system, which will monitor all instances of my cloud-solution. I already have a monitoring application, which is able to do tests on one instance of my cloud-solution. The thing is that the number of deployed cloud-solutions changes in time - it can grow, it can decrease. What I need is an app that will be able to run as many instances of my monitoring application, as many cloud-solutions I have. I wonder which Azure service would be the best to run those monitoring apps.
I need to be able to:

- run as many monitoring apps as I need
- shut them down (and remove) when a given cloud-solution is not used anymore and doesn't need to be monitored

I was thinking about Azure Container Instance and Web Jobs. I am not sure if there are any other reasonable choices. Azure Container Instance seems to be nice, however i don't fully understand if I'd need to create separate instances of this service per one monitoring app or should I have one instance of it to run multiple containers.

Answer (score 1):

ACI would probably be the easiest one here, App Services add way to much overhead, in my opinion, but they will probably be cheaper, but harder to maintain.

With ACI you would just create a container group per instance of the cloud app you are monitoring. So if you monitoring solution consists of a single container - this means use a single instance of ACI to host your solution. if your solution consists of multiple containers - the same applies, you can host multiple containers in the same ACI container group.

I'd advice against having multiple different monitoring solutions in a single container group, since it would make it harder to manage those.